# php, mysql - Combine result into multidimension associate array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have the following MySQL database :

```
    | id         | sessionId   | time                |
    |------------|-------------|---------------------|
    | 54         |           4 | 2013-03-23 09:00:00 |
    | 55         |           4 | 2013-03-23 09:15:00 |
    | 56         |           5 | 2013-04-20 01:00:00 |
    | 57         |           5 | 2013-04-20 15:15:00 |
    | 58         |           5 | 2013-04-20 19:15:00 |
```

I am trying to return an array as so:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sessionId] => 4
                [time] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2013-03-23 09:00:00
                        [1] => 2013-03-23 09:15:00
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sessionId] => 5
                [time] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2013-04-20 01:00:00
                        [1] => 2013-04-20 15:15:00
                        [2] => 2013-04-20 19:15:00
                    )

            )

    )
```

So far running this query

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Exercise_Lists_New` WHERE `patientId` = 381");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $sessionIds[] = array("sessionId" =>$row['sessionId'], "time" => array($row['time']));
    }
    print_r($sessionIds,true);
```

Gives me the follwing

```
    Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sessionId] => 4
                    [time] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2013-03-23 09:00:00
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sessionId] => 4
                    [time] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2013-03-23 09:15:00
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [sessionId] => 5
                    [time] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2013-04-20 01:00:00
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [sessionId] => 5
                    [time] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2013-04-20 15:15:00
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [sessionId] => 5
                    [time] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2013-04-20 19:15:00
                        )

                )

        )
```

So i would like to group all the 'time' that share the same 'sessionId' together. 
What would be the best way to do this using php.

Thanks

Comment: If you want the data you get from the query `GROUP`'ed, why do you insist on doing so in PHP? Why not use `GROUP_CONCAT`, `GROUP BY`, or any other way of grouping a resultset. Also: Stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if ( !isset($sessionIds[$row['sessionId']]) ) {
        $sessionIds[$row['sessionId']] = array(
            'sessionId' => $row['sessionId'],
            'time'      => array()
        );
    }
    $sessionIds[$row['sessionId']]['time'][] = $row['time'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    sessionId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(time) AS `Times`
FROM mytable
GROUP BY    sessionId
```

You can use group_concat of mysql for this. This will give you results as comma seperated field which you can explode with php to get an array.

Output :

```
| sessionId   | time                                                           |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------- |
|           4 | 2013-03-23 09:00:00 , 2013-03-23 09:15:00                      |
|           5 | 2013-04-20 01:00:00 , 2013-04-20 15:15:00 , 2013-04-20 19:15:00|
```

EDITED :

```
$query  =   "   SELECT
                    sessionId,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(time) AS `Times`
                FROM mytable
                GROUP BY    sessionId";

$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$result_array   =   array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $result_array[$i]['sessionId']  = $row['sessionId'];
    $result_array[$i]['time']       = explode(',',$row['Times']);
    $i++;
}
print_r($result_array,true);
```

Result

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sessionId] => 4
                [time] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2013-03-23 09:00:00
                        [1] => 2013-03-23 09:15:00
                    )

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [sessionId] => 5
                [time] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2013-04-20 01:00:00
                        [1] => 2013-04-20 15:15:00
                        [2] => 2013-04-20 19:15:00
                    )

            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip one level off that array, and use sessionID as the key, e.g.

```
$sessionIDs = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $sessionIds[$row['sessionID']][] = $row['time'];
}
```

This'll give you something like:

```
$arr = array(
     'id' => array(time1, time2, time3, ...),
     'id' => arraY(...)
     etc..
);
```

Note that you're losing one row in your code, as you do a `fetch()` call OUTSIDE of your loop, then immediately overwrite that `$row` with the fetch call in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Exercise_Lists_New` WHERE `patientId` = 381");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
    $sessionIds[$row['sessionId']]['sessionId'] = $row['sessionId'];
    $sessionIds[$row['sessionId']]['time'][] = $row['time'];
}

print_r($sessionIds):

Array
   (
       [4] => Array
           (
               [sessionId] => 4
               [time] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => 2013-03-23 09:00:00
                       [1] => 2013-03-23 09:15:00
                   )

           )

       [5] => Array
           (
               [sessionId] => 5
               [time] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => 2013-04-20 01:00:00
                       [1] => 2013-04-20 15:15:00
                       [2] => 2013-04-20 19:15:00
                   )
           )

   )
```

Comment: this gives me multiple sessionIDs